# groovy: @Lazy annotation does not work in trait

Tags: groovy, traits, lazy-initialization

I am trying to use the @Lazy annotation (http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/#xform-Lazy) in a trait to initialise an object only if used.

```
trait MyTrait{
  @Lazy String test = {
    new Exception().printStackTrace()
    return 'test'
  }()
}
```

The object is created regardless is used or not. I have added a printStackTrace in the initialisation closure to make sure I don't call the variable inadvertently. The object gets created when the class implementing the trait is instantiated.

Comment: This is not surprising.   In all of the talks I heard about Traits at G2One Cedric said, "Unless the documentation SAYS it will work with Traits, most annotations will NOT work with Traits."

Comment: You could do it manually as a workaround, by checking for an existing value in a custom getter

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug. The `@Lazy` does not work in trait's. You should create an issue ticket with Groovy for this to be corrected.

To prove the issue, I have extended your code to create a test (run as a simple groovy script) that shows that `@Lazy` works for a `Class`, but fails the assertion when used on a `trait`:

```
    class MyBase{
      @Lazy String test = { 'test' }()
    }
    class TestBaseClass extends MyBase{}
    def tb = new TestBaseClass();

    //Dump the current state to output an assert test hasn't been initialized
    println "Testing @Lazy on a Class.."
    println tb.dump()
    assert tb.dump().contains('test=null') //FOR A CLASS, THIS WILL SUCCEED

    //Access the test property causing initialization
    println "Accessing the test property."
    assert tb.test

    //Dump the current state to output an assert test has now been initialized
    println tb.dump()
    assert tb.test == 'test'

    trait MyTrait{
      @Lazy String test = { 'test' }()
    }
    class TestClass implements MyTrait{}
    def t = new TestClass();

    //Dump the current state to output an assert test hasn't been initialized
    println "\nTesting @Lazy on a Trait.."
    println t.dump()
    assert t.dump().contains('test=null') //FOR A TRAIT, THIS WILL FAIL THE ASSERTION - A BUG?

    //Access the test property causing initialization
    println "Accessing the test property."
    assert t.test

    //Dump the current state to output an assert test has now been initialized
    println t.dump()
    assert t.test == 'test'
```

Comment: If you would prefer that I open a ticket with Groovy, let me know and I would be happy to do it for you.

Comment: Pretty sure Cedric already knows, but feel free to ticket it.  When Traits came out, he said that most AST annotations wouldn't work with Traits, unless the docs said otherwise.

Comment: Did he say that he expected to work to enhance traits to work with annotations? Meaning is this expected behavior or is it possible that @Lazy was overlooked?

Comment: I have created a Jira ticket with Groovy for this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7759

Comment: I think if you put in a ticket, and it gets votes, it'll get worked on.   There are quite a few annotations.  Or, if you want, do a pull and see if you can get it working. :)